# How to show text as it is from text file from asset folder in Android

Tags: java, android, encoding, iso, utf

I am reading a file from Assets folder in Android. I am using below method to execute this part. But I am seeing every (") character are displayed as (?). I tried many online text converter but didn't work. What changes i need to do to display it exactly the way it is in text file in asset folder. Thanks in advance

```
private static CharSequence readEula(Activity activity) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets()
                    .open(ASSET_FILE)));
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line).append('\n');

            byte[] latin1 = buffer.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            return new String(latin1);

            //return buffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
        }
    }
```

Regards

Comment: `encoded text as it is` ... encoded to **what**? Base64, AES encoding? RSA encoding? or plain UTF-8? or maybe it's Windows CP-1252?

Comment: I am not sure what encoding it is but i am directly copying it from Microsoft Word

Comment: Is it even a **text** file? or is it a **doc** or **docx** (or an **rtf**) file?

Comment: No it is plain text file (.txt)

Comment: What does it show, opening it in your **NotePad** (not an advanced text editor, such as Notepad++ or UltraEdit) - just the plain NotePad?

Comment: Notepad it shows perfect ("). But while running in android it shows it as (?)

Comment: Windows uses the CP-1252 encoding. Android uses UTF-8. Try to open your text file in an **advanced** editor (Notepad++, UltraEdit, ...) and choose "Save As", choose the UTF-8 encoding (optionally setting the Unix line terminators). Now it will open perfectly in Android (After you remove the lines which set the encoding in your code!)

Comment: Did you try to just return buffer.toSting() ?